# css selector for sibling's child

Tags: css

I want to use css to target every "info" class that has an "error" class two divs above. Is there a way to do this with css? For example, I want the "info" class to have a red border if the field-label above it has an "error" class.

[image]

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to your question.  Adding only an image of code is not helpful [Read Why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: btw, in your image, `.info` is not inside `.error` - based on your example, you could try `.error + .input-field > .info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.error + .input-field > .info{
     attribute:value     
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
.error + .input-field .info {}
```

`.error + .input-field` will select only `.input-field` div that is immediately preceded by the `.error` div. So the above code will select any element with `.info` class, which is inside `.input-field` div.

```
.error + .input-field > .info {}
```

The code above will select any `.info` element which is direct children of `.input-field` div.

```
.error + .input-field > .info:nth-child(1) {}
```

The code above will select first instance of `.info` element which is direct children of `.input-field` div.